# std::map, std::equal_range, and comparison function

Tags: c++, maps

If I have a map/multimap with keys inserted using a comparison function (functor), is it possible to use map::equal_range with a comparison function as well?  For instance, if I have a std::map m, and keys:

```
sometype a.getVal == 101
sometype b.getVal == 112 <-first pair (using equal_range)
sometype c.getVal == 113
sometype d.getVal == 121 <-second pair (using equal_range)
```

and I wanted to get a range/set of keys 11* is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good reason why you cannot use `map::equal_range()` with a custom comparer: it would defeat the asociativity of the container. It can be done, but the algorithm would be O(n) instead of O(log(n)), since it would have to compare all `map` elements regardless of their position.

I think the best solution for your problem would be a custom function that uses  `map::lower_bound()` and `map::upper_bound()` to find your interval limits. Something like:

```
typedef std::map<int>::iterator Iter;
std::pair<Iter, Iter> CustomEqualRange (const std::map<int>& theMap, int lowerBound, int range)
{
  Iter lower = theMap.lower_bound(lowerBound);
  Iter upper = theMap.upper_bound(lowerBound + range);
  return std::make_pair(lower, upper);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `equal_range` function doesn't offer that, but you could call `lower_bound` passing a value with `getVal == 110`, and `upper_bound` passing a value with `getVal == 120`. That pair of iterators should represent all values in the half-open range [110, 120).